Authenticate Web API under On-Premise SharePoint site not working in Microsoft Edge
I have created a Web API in C# that is being called from a SharePoint On-Premise environment. I have had the idea to deploy the Web API solution in the same IIS site where the SharePoint site collection is deployed in order to avoid CORS and Authentication issues. However this looks to be working in one of the environments (with 1 back-end and 1 front-end servers) but it is not working in production environment (with 1 back-end and 2 front-end servers with a load-balancer).
I have protected the methods of the Web API by using the "Authorize" attribute as follows:
[Authorize(Roles = "Admins-AD-GROUP")]

Also for production environment there is SSO configured, but it is still prompting for credentials.
The idea will be as follow:

Users access to the SharePoint intranet https://intranetexample.com/
Users from the SharePoint intranet calls the Web API: https://intranetexample.com/apps/WebAPI

When users access to https://intranetexample.com/ users can call to the web api using javascript without entering their username and password again as the SharePoint site and Web API are deployed under the same hostname https://intranetexample.com/
Also, as already mentioned, I can authenticate to the web api using Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, but I can't from Microsoft Edge. Also, I think the host "intranetexample.com" is also added in the trust sites under "Internet Options" (I cannot see it as the settings are blocked by the IT department)
Anyone has any idea of what could be the problem?
Thank you so much in advance.

Maybe you need to check if the SSO settings are correctly passing the authentication information to the Web API.

@YurongDai Thank you for your answer, however, even if I open the browser in incognito mode, it is requesting the credentials (as expected) but eventhough I entered them correctly it never authenticates.. It gives me the impression as it is trying to use a different authentication method.

For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, so I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com,
there will be professional technicians to provide further assistance.

I was able to fix the issue by enabling the FederatedAuthentication in the web.config of the application where the web service was hosted.
I have deployed the web service with the following structure:
SharePoint web application - APPS (removes the modules used in SharePoint to do not interfere with the web service application) - Web Service App
From the modules at the begining I was removing all except:

SPWindowsClaimsAuthentication

Now the only modules I am removing (because it causes exceptions are):

SharePoint14Module
DesignHttpModule

Also, I had to change the application pool of the Web Service App to use the same application pool as the SharePoint Web App, otherwise it was causing "The farm is unavailable" exception in "SessionAuthentication"
